# Last RUN column changes quickly and not respect the shedule_interval

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

A default_args is :

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'sakila_sakila',
    'start_date': days_ago(2),
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),
    'retries': 1,
}
```

The definition of the DAG is:

```
with DAG(dag_id='query_hook_mysql', schedule_interval='*/5 * * * *', default_args=default_args) as dag:
```

It means that the DAG will be trigger every five minutes.

The UTC in the UI is :
[image]

After put at ON my DAG, I saw In the Last Run column : 2020-08-05 00:00

[image]

After some seconds, the the Last Run column become : 2020-08-05 00:05

1. Why it changes so faster ? The 5 minutes is not arrive yet.
2. What is the link between retry_delay and retries ?

Thank you.

Comment: (2) `retry_delay` means delay (seconds) b/w successive retry-attempts whereas `retries` is the no of times to attempt retry

Comment: For example: retries:1, retry_delay:4 minutes. If i understand, it means that each time before the task is failed, this task wil be retries 1 times after 4 minutes !!!